# Intellij Idea, Git : Revert commit mechanism not working

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I am working on managing our project through GIT. I have Intellij Idea and Git running. The git project is running on one of our servers, which are we connecting through ssh.

Currently, everything is working fine except reverting commits. Somehow the reverts are either failing or not changing anything.

For reverting any last commit, I am going in `VCS-->Git-->Reset head(Hard)`, but it is not helping. Before doing that I have pushed commit to master and I am currently(always) working on master. Is that a problem and is that causing revert to not function.

Now, as you can see in the screenshot below, the last commit named `Test1234` is responsible for removing a simple `System.out` and I am trying to revert it commit `Test123`, which adds a `System.out`. What am I doing wrong?

Output of `git status` :

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

[image]

The commits in GitGraken  :

[image]

[image]

I don't know which information related to git to post. Kindly let me know if anything is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try right click to the previous commit in IntelliJ and choose reset current branch to here

When I activate this plugin right it works as the previous image

[image]

Comment: In GitGraken you mean, first thing I tried. And then I performed a pull in IDE, nothing happened. In Intellij Git logs, I don't see option to revert.

Comment: Thank you. My Intellij is old, worked with a new one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try github's commandline, you'd be able to identify the problem. I also had problems, github's commandline is much better and works faster (especially for reverting / deleting commits).

See http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html as reference

Comment: I am not using Github... But the commands in the documentation proved useful when things go bad with git plugins.